# Function LogOff in NavBar does not work in MVC5

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, navbar

A project was created in MVC 5 and I am implementing a [Bootwatch](https://bootswatch.com/) template but something is not working well in my NavBar Menu.

1.- No esta funcionando mi boton de "LogOff", al llamar al script de mi _LoginPartial este no se ejecuta y mi boton simplemente no hace nada.

My _LoginPartial.cshtml:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Hola: " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "! ", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
    }
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

My _Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Muebles Pangal</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")     

     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-success">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Muebles Pangal</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Categorias")">Categorias </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Productoes")">Productos </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Ubicacions")">Proveedores </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Usuarios")">Usuarios </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")    

                </form>

            </div>
        </nav>
        <br />
        </div>

        <div class="container body-content">
            @RenderBody()
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Sistema Bodega</p>
            </footer>
        </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>


        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

My AccountController.cs:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

2.- The color of my NavBar on the right side is not equal to the elements on the left side, and when I inspect my console I throw an element to `a{}` which changes its color, makes a change in other elements such as for example the `@Html.ActionLink` and not in the element that you want to modify.

Is this really the element of my NavBar that you want to change color?

[image: Console]

it's the second time I've been working with MVC 5 and it's the first time that I'm implementing a template, does anyone know what's going on?
any help for me?

Comment: is it giving any error ??

Comment: Yes.. You are using Form inside form --- Remove parent form As In ASP.NET Only form (parent form work)

Comment: It is not giving any error, the button does not work and I can not change the css style @ZahidMustafa

Comment: Well, I told you solution ... Nested form doesn't work in ASP.NET.

Comment: you can solve it by doing so:
<div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
</div>

Comment: Is that `AuthenticationManager.SignOut` reached (put breakpoint on that method)? Nested form can't work properly even it placed in partial views, also you may include CSS styles which related to the anchor links.

Comment: @tetsuya-yamamoto it doesn't matter either you have nested form in partial views or normal views it will be rendered as one form and that is parent form

Comment: You can not enter the method, so putting a break point does not help my problem :( @TetsuyaYamamoto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET can't render nested form. Only parent form is rendered so for keeping form in Partial page

replace

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
@Html.Partial("My_LoginPartial")
</form>
```

with

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {


            using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" }))
            {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                 <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Hola: " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "! ", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
                </li>
                <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
            </ul>
            }
        }
        else
        {
        <form class ="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0"
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
            </ul>
        </form>
        }
```

Comment: I'm not understanding your answer, could I be more specific or put more code? you tell me that removing the element @ html.partial ("_ LoginPartial.cshtml") will fix the problem?

Comment: Please check now.. What i mean ... Just replace your form tag with div  in My _Layout.cshtml and make no changes in My _LoginPartial.cshtml:

Comment: Can you identify which element of my bootstrap.css is the one that can be modified in color?

Comment: Did you try the above solution

Comment: The logoff solution works correctly, but I still can not change the css style !! what a puzzle!

Comment: @fytoahse please give vote to my answer.  I will tell another way to do both things

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171041/discussion-between-fytoahse-and-zahid-mustafa).

Comment: Please check now